# gnuplot boxplot percentile instead 1st and 3rd quartile

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

How can I draw boxplot in gnuplot with box that is drawn around the region between 1% and 99% instead of 1st and 3rd quartile?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You cannot, those limits are fixed. You'd need to calculate these values with an other program and then plot the box in gnuplot.

Comment: Thanks Christoph, says I could calculate the percentile values, how can I tell gnuplot to use these value for box_min and box_high to draw boxplot (not candletick), I didn't find this part in the manual.

Comment: You can't. The meaning of a box plot's elements is fixed, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Box_plot. If you really want to change that, you'll need to plot using candlesticks.

Comment: Alright. I will have to use candlesticks. Thanks again. Christoph.